# Where are class constructor parameters defined in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, class, di

If you see AbstractExpress class for PayPal payment method, you could see:

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
 * @param \Magento\Paypal\Model\Express\Checkout\Factory $checkoutFactory
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Session\Generic $paypalSession
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerUrl
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
    \Magento\Paypal\Model\Express\Checkout\Factory $checkoutFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Session\Generic $paypalSession,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerUrl
) {
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    $this->_checkoutFactory = $checkoutFactory;
    $this->_paypalSession = $paypalSession;
    $this->_urlHelper = $urlHelper;
    $this->_customerUrl = $customerUrl;
    parent::__construct($context);
    $parameters = ['params' => [$this->_configMethod]];
    $this->_config = $this->_objectManager->create($this->_configType, $parameters);
}
```

The question is: how does the system know which parameters to pass to constructor and of what type?  I think they are defined somewhere, but I have looked at di.xml files of this module but I have only find this:

```
<type name="Magento\Paypal\Controller\Express\AbstractExpress">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="paypalSession" xsi:type="object">Magento\Paypal\Model\Session</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Only payPal Session appears (although of different type).

Answer (score 11):

## Explanation

To pass parameters to contructors you may use the direct injection mechanism in Magento2 (look for `di.xml`).

Defining an argument in a class constructor in Magento 2 is very similar to Magento 1 `Mage::getSingleton` method. You will get a singleton class of the type you required in the constructor.

Magento will **just pass you a singleton instance of the object you required** in the constructor by using a reflection mechanism.
If you declare a parameter of type `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session` you will automatically get that class as singleton.
Just like doing `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')` in Magento 1.

If you **need to pass arguments** you problably need to use a **Factory**. Using a factory is like the `Mage::getModel` in Magento 1.

Factories are automatically created by Magento 2 framework, you do not need to define them unless you really need. Just add `Factory` to your class name.

In you example I see you use `\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory`. That class is a factory for `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order` and you can use it do instantiate orders like `Mage::getModel('sales/order')` in Magento 1.

If you need to pass arguments to a factory constructor you just have to pass them to `create` method with an hash.

For example:

```
$this->myObjectFactory->create(['myparam' => $myvalue]);
```

This will create a new object and will pass `$myvalue` to the constructor argument called `$myparam`. No matter of its position.

## Example 1: You need to access customer session in your class

```
<?php
namespace MyNS\MyModule\Model;

class MyClass {
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function getCustomerSession() {
        return $this->customerSession;
    }
}
```

In the previous example, an instance of `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session` is "automatically" passed to `$customerSession` parameter. Magento **just detects you are asking for that class in your constructor** and it will pass you an instance of such object.

This is an equivalend of: `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')` in Magento 1.

Have a look here to understand how it does: `Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory`

## Example 2: You need to load an order information

```
<?php
namespace MyNS\MyModule\Model;

class MyClass {
    protected $orderInterfaceFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterfaceFactory $orderInterfaceFactory
    ) {
        $this->orderInterfaceFactory = $orderInterfaceFactory;
    }

    public function getOrder($orderId) {
        $order = $this->orderInterfaceFactory->create();
        $order->load($orderId);

        return $order;
    }
}
```

In this example **you do not need a singleton**, you need an order instance.
To achieve this you need to require a **Factory Class**. A Factory Class is a special class that can create class instances.

This is the equivalent of `Mage::getModel('sales/order')` in Magento 1.

## Factory classes:

Factory classes can be both manually or automatically defined. If you create your own class and you do not create the Factory class, Magento **will automatically build it for you**.

So, if you create:

```
<?php
namespace MyNS\MyModule\Model;

class MyClass {
    public function myMethod() { return "foo"; }
}
```

and you need to access to and instance of it, you can just ask for `MyClassFactory`, even if you did not define such class:

```
<?php
namespace MyNS\MyModule\Model;

class MyOtherClass {
    protected $myClassFactory;

    public function __construct(
        MyClassFactory $myClassFactory
    ) {
        $this->myClassFactory = $myClassFactory;
    }

    public function myOtherMethod() {
        $myClassInstance = $this->myClassFactory->create();
        $myClassInstance->myMethod();
    }
}
```

## Interfaces and preferences

In Magento2, when you ask for a class direct injection, is recommended to ask for an **Interface Class**.

In my previous example (Example #2), I do not require an `Order` class, but and `OrderInterface` class. This is the best way because interfaces are supposed to be always compatible between Magento different versions.

You question may be: **An interface is not a class, how can I instantiate it?**

The answer is in the Magento 2 prefernce mechanism (it is the equivalent of the rewrite mechanism in Magento 1).

`OrderInterface` is mapped to `Magento\Sales\Model\Order` in `di.xml` file of `magento-sales` module:

```
...
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface" type="Magento\Sales\Model\Order"/>
...
```

So, when you ask for `OrderInterface`, Magento will give you an instance of `Magento\Sales\Model\Order`.

If your module need to rewrite `Magento\Sales\Model\Order`, you can define your new preference pointing to another class. This new class **MUST** implement `OrderInterface`.

This allows a perfect integration between modules.

Comment: Can you give a real example, please? My brain is very tired trying to understand this but I cannot still figure it out. For example, I have this controller definition, class Failure extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action. To this, I need to have a Cart Management instance, so I have added it to the constructor, but a runtime error occurs telling that the parameters for constructor are incorrect. Maybe what you have explained is aplicable to new objects, however, in my case I need to get existing objects according to current user session in order to finish my payment gateway.

Comment: Updated my post with more detailed information. Hope it helps.

Comment: Like already mentioned in the question, instead of creating a factory, you can also set constructor arguments with the type configuration in the di.xml like described here: http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_argument_replacement. This way each module can override constructor arguments. To create a class instance with a complete new set of constructor arguments, you can create a virtual type like described here: http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_virtual_types

Comment: nice explanation